# How to Optimize PDF and PCL creation in C# using active reports3

Tags: c#

I am working on Optimizing performace for one my batch process at work.
This batch process reads data from couple of tables,
Person --> employment
Assemble the domain objects

```
 Person
{
//person fields
List<IEmployment> EmploymentList
}
IEmployment
{
//employment fields
}
```

, create PDF and PCL files.
I need to create a PCL and PDF file for each person.
Currently I am looping through each peson, creating instance of ActiveReport setting person as data source to ActiveReport, Creating PCL, creating PDF and exit.
I am loading 500 person records at a time, create pcl's and pdf's and read next 500 unprocessed person records.
This is taking around 5 mins to complete 500 records, at times we might have 30,000 records to process which is equating to 5 hrs. I am trying to optimize if. Please let me know if there is a better way of generating this bulk pdf's and pcl's.

Comment: are using threading? http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/05/multithreading-using-activereports.html